# How to consequently animate several elements with react-native-reanimated?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

Assuming I have two `View`s and I need to animate them consequently, i.e.

1. First view animates
2. First view finishes animation, second view animates

How exactly do I do that with `react-native-reanimated`? I've found very little information in the onboarding docs, so what is the best practice of doing this?

Answer (score -1):

> I need to animate them consequently

It's a little bit complicated to understand what you want to achieve.
I would advise to

1. Clone the repo

```
git clone git@github.com:software-mansion/react-native-reanimated.git
```

2. Run

```
  yarn
  cd Example
  yarn
  cd ios && pod install && cd .. # if using IOS devices
  yarn start
```

You are going to have access to plenty of examples

[image]

Comment: yeah, not it, actually, I have traversed through them. The goal is to replicate Animated.sequence([]) behavior, but with Reanimated instead